# URLs longer parts than 255 characters cause 403 forbidden in Laravel???

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create an endpoint out of a base64 string, but only end up with a 403 forbidden error when used. My first though is that there is a limit on how long a url can be?

**EDIT**

It seems after some *exploration* the MAX the string can be is 255 characters, after that it blows up??

Here is my Route setup

```
....
Route::get('/{glob}', 'GrantController@Init');
....
```

Here is my GrantController

```
Class GrantController Extends BaseController
{
    protected   $str  = null,
                $obj  = null;

    /**
     * Run the trap..
     *
     * @param $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function init($data)
    {
        return \View::make('debug.dump', [
                'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

And /Views/debug/dump.php

```
echo $data . '<br />';
echo 'Length: ' . strlen($data); // 255 MAX
```

Comment: ["Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths above 255 bytes"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1) .. though you'd expect a 414 in response

Comment: I would also first assume the server, but could be a soft limit of laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a precision on msturdy comment, the URI RFC explain the design of any uri:

> URI producers should use names that conform to the DNS syntax, even when use of DNS is not    immediately apparent, and should limit these names to no more than 255 characters in length.

[RFC3986 - URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3)

Comment: Would be very strict of Laravel though. I think the user decides. The browser and subsystems may pose the limits though: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: Could also come from the server itself... ehime are you using a proper server (apache/nginx) or are you using php -S / artisan serve?

Comment: As I understand it, Laravel's routing and request handling is based heavily on Symfony, and I can't see that Symfony limits the length of the request anywhere...